# Trioxane fuel tablet recrystalization

Tags: crystal-structure

I had a bunch of old military trioxane fuel tablets.  I decided to open all of the packets, maybe a dozen, and place the contents in an empty tin coffee can with a plastic lid.  I put the can in a dark closet.  I let it sit undisturbed for several months.  Upon opening the can, I saw crystal structures growing off of the sides of the tin can.  They appear to be of a lightweight somewhat flexible plastic composition and are flammable in the same way that the rest of the fuel is.  If I disturb them by damaging them or removing them, more will grow over time, if I let the container sit.  What is this reaction?  Has anyone witnessed this before?

Comment: Trioxane is a trimer of formaldehyde. I wonder if you're under enough of an equilibrium to form paraformaldehyde.

Answer (score 1):

It's *[subliming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition))* (aided in this case by decomposition) and re-depositing.

Substances that turn directly from solid to vapor (e.g. naphthalene, water ice) are said to *sublime*, rather than *evaporate*. The inverse, changing from vapor to solid, is termed *deposition*.

When water vapor deposits on very cold surfaces, such as "dry ice", it grows into amazing dendritic crystals:

[image: water ice crystals on dry ice]

Comment: The substance sublimating is 1,3,5-trioxane.  www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/732431.pdf